# Как делать правильно push & pull через рычаг

Tags: git, оптимизация

Подскажите пожалуйста, как называются подобные рычаги для компьютеров, и есть ли вообще такое ?

Чтобы мог забиндить на эти кнопки действия:

Рычаг вперед - `git push`
Рычаг на себя - `git pull`

Хочется что-то похожее на рычаг управления двигателями самолета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или хотя бы такое ..
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скрипты никто не отменял....но я бы пользовался GUI для Git.

Comment: Мне кажется, это лучше у геймеров спросить, чем у программистов. Вероятно среди геймпадов и есть что-то готовое уже.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не соотносится с тематикой сайта. Лучше спросить на специализированных форумах (геймеров, например).

Comment: Первое число прошло, немного опоздали...